# AJAX request in ColdFusion

Tags: javascript, ajax, coldfusion

How can I do a AJAX request in ColdFusion?

I have my javascript:

```
function getdata(){
    var formElements=document.getElementById("CFForm_1").elements;    
    var data=[];
    for (var i=0; i<formElements.length; i++){
        if(formElements[i].name == 'customersid')
            data.push({'customersid':document.getElementById("customersid").value});
        if(formElements[i].name == 'customerstoid')
            data.push({'customerstoid':document.getElementById("customerstoid").value});
    }

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "get",
        url: "components/BillingCalc.cfc",
        data: {
                method:"ajaxGetTotalCost",
                data: data.join()
            },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function( objResponse ){

        }
    });
  }
```

My component:

```
component displayName="Calc" {

remote function ajaxGetTotalCost(data){
    data = deserializeJSON(arguments.data);
    WriteDump(data); abort;
}
```

I am getting the error: JSON parsing failure at character 2:'o' in [object Object],[object Object] 
Does anyone knows how to do AJAX request in CF?

Comment: `data: data.join()` is not how you create json. coldfusion will not be able to deserialize it as if it were json.

Comment: If you are using jQuery, why are you using `document.getElementById()`? Use jQuery to get those values. `data.push( $('#customersid') )` I have found this to be a great tool to put form data into json easily, https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object

Answer (score 1):

This function:

```
remote function ajaxGetTotalCost(data){
data = deserializeJSON(arguments.data);
WriteDump(data); abort;
}
```

is not complete.  It's at the stage where you have to call it from a ColdFusion page, not with javascript.  That will enable you to see the results of the `writedump(data)` command to ensure it's what you expect.  You have to add more code to the function to get it to produce a variable javascript can receive, and then return that variable to whatever is calling the function.

Comment: I fixed that using JSON.stringify(data), but I am getting parsererror when I return data from CFC to AJAX

Comment: @Apprentice123456 - Please update your question and append the current code AND error message.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to `dataType` attribute you are passing with `$.ajax()` method. `dataType: "json"` indicates your AJAX request is expecting `JSON` data as a response. But in your case you are simply returning `DUMP` of the deserialized JSON, which is `HTML` not `JSON`. So if you want it to work properly, then you need to return `JSON` data from your ColdFusion function. You can try this and see if it works.

```
remote function ajaxGetTotalCost(data){
   data = deserializeJSON(arguments.data);
   return serializeJSON(data));
}
```